# How can I make it so that the image is the same height as its container and has the parallax effect?

Tags: html, css

I want the section of the website to look like this:
[image]

But right now mine looks like this:

[image]

How can I increase the height of the image on the right to cover the full height of the `about-sec` container? And how can I then increase the height of the `about-sec` container so that the whole image can be seen to the right as shown in the example above while keeping the parallax effect?

Here is my CSS code:

```
.about-sec {
  width: 100%;
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2% 0.5% 10% 0.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-half {
    width: 50%;
    position: abosulte;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    /*  */

}

.right-half {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("aboutSectionImage.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    height: 6em;
    display: flex;

    /* padding-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 10%; */
}
```

Here is my React/HTML code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './aboutSection.css';


class AboutSection extends React.Component {

    render() { 
        return (
            <div className="about-sec" >
               <div className="left-half">
                    asd
               </div>
               <div className="right-half">
                   Hi
                   <br></br>
                   df
               </div>
               
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default AboutSection;
```

---

**EDIT**

The image to the right of the screen works and now I'm trying to add a parallax scrolling effect. The effect works for me but the I'm not sure how to make the image only take up half the page (right side). When I set `background-size: cover;` it should take up the whole size of the div, in this case, the `right-half` div. For some reason the image is super huge and it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

CSS code:

```
 *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .about-sec{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 90vh;
  }
  .left-half{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: white;
  }
  .right-half{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url("aboutSectionImage.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below `css` code for your reference. You really don't need the `position: absolute;` on your `right-half` class. You should only use `positioning` to do minute changes and you should not use it to do your layout. It seems that you are also not familiar on how `flexbox` works check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) to familiarize yourself with it.

Edit: The reason the image is behaving like you have described is because of the `background-size` property that has been set to `cover`. I've set it specifically for this case to `50%` for its `width` and `100%` for its `height`. You can learn more about the said property and its syntax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.about-sec{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 120vh;
}
.left-half{
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.right-half{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parallax {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mmppicture.co.in%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2022%2F01%2FPicsart-Background-218-901x1080.jpg&f=1&nofb=1');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content{
  color: black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="about-sec">
      <div class="left-half">
      left
      </div>
      <div class="right-half">
        <div class="parallax">
          <p class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea labore, culpa quos impedit exercitationem odit repudiandae ipsa aperiam? Dolor dolores omnis doloremque facere ipsam vitae, minima sint pariatur veritatis blanditiis.
    Aliquid voluptates deserunt est, error dolorem quasi similique sapiente veniam quos facere beatae laborum adipisci earum perferendis perspiciatis non fugit repellendus officia deleniti libero animi doloribus? Tempore quae vitae autem?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I updated my question because I wanted to keep the parallax scrolling effect but I'm having some trouble implementing it. Would you happen to know why the image isn't the same size as the `right-half` div, rather much bigger? Thanks again

Comment: @SimerusM it's because of the `background-size` property that has been set to `cover`, we can set the `width` and `height` specifically by setting its width and height. I've edited the snippet to apply the *parallax scrolling effect* as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar example you can update class and dom structure, here I use `bootstrap 4.6+`

```css
.fdb-block {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  width: 100%;
}

.col-fill-right {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1900/1000");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

@media all and (max-width:768px) {
  .col-fill-right {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="fdb-block">
  <div class="col-fill-right">
  </div>

  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-5 text-center">
        <h1>Froala Blocks</h1>
        <p class="lead">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>
        <p class="mt-4 mb-5"><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://www.froala.com">Button</a></p>

        <p>Follow us on</p>
        <p>
          <a href="https://www.froala.com" class="mx-2 text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.froala.com" class="mx-2 text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.froala.com" class="mx-2 text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.froala.com" class="mx-2 text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.froala.com" class="mx-2 text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```